# Prove that this is true

Tags: induction

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}i^x = P_{x+1}(n)$$                     Let x be any nonnegative integer and show that there is a polynomial $P_{x+1}$ of degree $x+1$ for every $n$ greater than or equal to $1$.

Comment: why using induction?

Comment: it doesn't have to be induction if you can do it another way.

Comment: See [Faulhaber's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula).

Comment: wow it's faulhaber's formula

Comment: does it also give the proof on the faulhaber's formula wikipedia page?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Prove that there exists a polynomial $Q_{x+1}(n)$ with the property that
[
Q_{x+1}(n+1)-Q_{x+1}(n)=n^x \,.
]

You can prove this for example by observing that $n+1-n, (n+1)^2-n^2,.., (n+1)^{x+1}-n^{x+1}$ are linearly independent, thus a basis for the space of polynomials of degree at most $x$ in the variable $n$.

Once you do this, you can easily prove that for the right constant $C$, which can be obtained by setting $n=1$, the polynomial 
[
P_{x+1}(n)=Q_{x+1}(n)+C \,,
]
works.

**Second solution**

$$(i+1)^{x+1}=i^{x+1}+(x+1)i^x +\sum_{j=2}^{x+1} \binom{x+1}{j} i^{k+1-j} \,.$$

Sum this from $i=1$ to $n$, cancel the common terms, and use induction by $x$.

Comment: so do I not need to do this by induction? I can prove this the way you have said?

Comment: N.S. can you like elaborate more or do something that helps me understand this better?